# Create singleton from a library dependency

Tags: typescript

I want to create a singleton of my own class which depends on google-auth-library.

You can create an oauthClient like so:

```js
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";

const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const getOauthClient = (
  clientId: string,
  clientSecret: string,
  redirectUrl: string
): OAuth2Client => {
  return new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
};
```

Therefore, I'm trying to add this instance which is gonna be created if you call getOauthClient into my OauthClient class that looks like this:

```js
class OauthClient{
  constructor(
    clientId: string,
    clientSecret: string,
    redirectUrl: string
  ){
    if(OauthClient._instance){
      throw new Error("Cannot initialize singleton class using new");
    }
  }

  private static _instance: OauthClient = getOauthClient(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  public static get instance(): OauthClient{
    return OauthClient._instance;
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, here's the code:

```js
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";

const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

class OauthClient{
  constructor() {
    throw new Error(
      "Cannot initialize singleton class using new. Use OauthClient.getInstance instead"
    );
  }

  private static instance: OauthClient;

  public static getInstance(
    clientId: string,
    clientSecret: string,
    redirectUrl: string
  ): OauthClient {
    if(!OauthClient.instance){
      this.instance = new OAuth2(
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        redirectUrl
      );
    }
    return OauthClient.instance;
  }
}
```